# Workaround for Unity5 iOS compile error with facebook-unity-sdk 6.2.1

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, compilation, facebook-unity-sdk

i am getting these errors when i try to compile on iOS:

on ios:
FBLinkShareParams *dialogParams = [[[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init] autorelease];
/Users/Daniel/Repositories/Unity5/FacebookTest/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.mm:561:73: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

/Users/Daniel/Repositories/Unity5/FacebookTest/Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.mm:662:15: No known class method for selector 'publishInstall:withHandler:'

now these don't  seem to be that much of a problem, so is there any Facebook developer here who can give as a fast workaround this? 
How is responsible for this at Facebook, why can't we contact them directly?

Comment: These errors have been resolved in v6.2.2 of the Facebook SDK for Unity.

Answer (score 7):

Put -fno-objc-arc in the compile flags of the FbUnityInterface.mm , and it will work

Comment: how do i set it only for that file? i know who to set the linker flag for the whole project, and if i do that i still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

Following user2018862's advice, this worked for me (setting the -fno-objc-arc flag for `FbUnityInterface.mm`), where `FbUnityInterface.mm` is found under the "Compiled Sources" section of the "Build Phases" pane.

[image]