# Unity Facebook SDK compile 'autorelease' is unavailable in 6.2.2

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Getting these errors on iOS Xcode compile with 6.2.2 of the unity SDK.:

> /Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.mm:569:73: 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
>
> /Assets/Facebook/Editor/iOS/FbUnityInterface.mm:670:15: No known class method for selector 'publishInstall:withHandler:'

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318048/workaround-for-unity5-ios-compile-error-with-facebook-unity-sdk-6-2-1) says it is fixed in 6.2.2 and I am using 6.2.2.

Comment: Nobody has an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the compile flag `-fno-objc-arc` to FbUnityInterface.mm.

In Unity, navigate to FbUnityInterface.mm in the project panel. In the section "Select platforms for plugin", check the box next to iOS.

Next, at the bottom of the "Platform settings" section, type `-fno-objc-arc` in the compile flags section.